# Laptop screen turning off after windows loads

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, display, multiple-monitors

I have a HP 2000-216NR Notebook-PC running windows 7 64 bit.

Last year I heavily broke its screen. I am connecting an external monitor to the VGA port in order to continue using it. I turn off my laptop screen by Winkey + P and choosing projector only.

Then last night, I just had an idea to replace my hardware laptop screen by taking out the other monitor's lcd screen. It's working properly, I can see the bios again. But after windows loads, the laptop screen was not turning on. So I decided to put back my vga monitor again and pressed WinKey + P choosing Duplicate/Extend/Disconnect Projector but the laptop screen still did not turn on.

I did some research and tried uninstalling the display adapter drivers in Device Manager. Restarted it and my laptop screen turns on again. But there are alot of features lost because of uninstalling the display adapter driver, like aero effects.

I can't play other games saying that my display adapter drivers is not up to date. I tried reinstalling the display adapter driver ,but the laptop screen does not turn on again. I think there's some wrong with my windows settings that makes my laptop screen to turn off.

I am planning to just reformat my laptop but is there any way to fix it without reformat?

**EDIT: I tried the 100% brightness but it still doesn't work**

Comment: Does your screen turn off or does the backlight turn off? You can check by shining a light on the screen.

Comment: @AdmiralFreebee what do you mean? The whole screen is turned off

Comment: On laptops it may seem as if the screen is off but in fact only the backlight is turned off. Your screen contains a light to illuminate the display. If the light is off, the screen may still be on.